# Why are my session lifetimes not expiring when they're supposed to?

Tags: php, session, cookies

When my users login, I want to set the amount of time before the session expires.
I've accomplished this by setting the lifetime in `session_set_cookie_params`.

When I look at the cookie's expiration date it says:

> Saturday, December 8, 3296 at 11:45:08 AM

But when I come back after an hour the cookie is there but my site won't recognize it. Why won't my site recognize or use the cookie?

Comment: Maybe you should share your code for the cookie handling to begin with.

Comment: Like I said `session_set_cookie_params` it's self explanatory.

Comment: Formatting and grammar fixes

Comment: You should include how the cookies look like in the browser (e.g. Chrome Developer Tools). It's possible that they aren't recognized or are not permanent (session vs. persistent cookies), or have flags like "SSL only" set. Without more details you likely won't get any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie contains only session identifier. The data itself is stored on server side. PHP periodically deletes expired sessions. When you're returning after one hour, session data is already lost and session ID from your cookie can't match to anything.

Chck out session.gc_maxlifetime (http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out